# Which one is correct between these two sentences

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

Which one is correct

> Students are more interested to study.
>
> Students are more interested in studying.

Please explain

Comment: Which do you think is correct, and why?  And why is this confusing?  We try not to answer these kind of "proofreading" questions.

Comment: Any good dictionary should list "to be interested in _+ something_" under "interested" along with example sentences.